# Possible to trigger rebuild when linked lib changes when using WebPack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

We are currently running a module system with Create-React-App where we have several in house npm libraries. When working on these libraries we use npm link with great success. The only annoying part is that after we build the linked npm module, we have to stop/restart the webpack dev server.

Is it possible to tell webpack to refresh itself when the linked npm node_module changes?